# error using DatePicker, I keep getting Not a valid date value even with the correct formatting. I need help, I can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: flask-wtforms, bootstrap-datepicker

I am working on a project and one of the modules are related to an appointment site using wtfform+DataField+flask
My form in appointment.html looks like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="myform">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form, novalidate=True, button_map={"submit": "primary"}) }}
```

my forms.py:

```
class DateForm(FlaskForm):
    date = DateField("Date", format="'%Y-%m-%d'", validators=[Optional()])
    hour = TimeField("Hour", format="'%H:%M'", validators=[Optional()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

My main.py

```
@app.route("/appointment", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def appointment():
    form = DateForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            session["date"] = form.date.data
            session["hour"] = form.hour.data
            return redirect(url_for('date'))
    return render_template("appointment.html", form=form, current_user=current_user)
```

```
@app.route('/date', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def date():
date = session["date"]
        hour = session["hour"]
        return render_template('date.html')
```

I have tested other alternatives but with the same result. No matter what, I'm still seeing the "Not a valid date value" and "Not a valid time value" messages.
I appreciate any help.
Thanks!!!

[appointment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmmTw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solved this problem by adding InputRequired() as validator y the form, just like this:

```
date = DateField("Fecha", validators=([InputRequired(), DataRequired()]))
hour = TimeField("Hora", validators=([InputRequired(), DataRequired()]))
```